# Fixed points of coupled ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-points

I am trying to find the fixed points of a set of coupled differential equations, which are as follows:
$y_1^\prime = y_2$, $y_2^\prime = -\sin(y_1)$

My first attempt involved integrating $y_2^\prime$, which lead to the solutions:
1. $(c,0)$
2. $(0,-c/t)$
3. $(\arcsin(c/t),-c/t)$

My second attempt involved logic, and I got the answer: $(0,n\pi)$ where $n$ is any integer.

I am unsure if either of these answers are correct, or what to do to get the correct answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for $(y_1, y_2)$ to be a fixed point, you want the right sides of your system of differential equations to be $0$.  No integration is needed.

Comment: That lead to the (0,nπ) answer I found, I tried it with integration and got that too. I guess that the fixed points would be just (0,nπ)?

Comment: Not quite: it's $y_2 = 0$, not $y_1 = 0$.  So $(n\pi, 0)$.